# Надо поправить форматирование на правках при репутации < 2000

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, предлагаемые-правки

Не то чтобы я grammar-nazi, но перед **Она** не хватает пробела. Я так понимаю проблема перевода?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На MSE сотрудник [сообщил, что всё исправлено](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/389369/1346379). И метку красную повесил (значит, и нам её повесить надо).

Comment: Хорошие новости! Но метку только модератор может поставить.

Comment: Ссылка, скорее всего, должна быть на [вопрос на MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423591/3240681).

Answer (score 4):

Это две разные строки:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14175
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17377

Склейка обеспечивается отдельно от переводов. Поэтому поправить это через механизм переводов можно лишь костылём - добавлением явного пробела в конце первой или в начале второй строки. Делать такой костыль я не считаю правильным.

Тем более, что проблемы с отсутствующими пробелами в некоторых склеенных текстах уже опубликованы на MSE, например, [Missing space in bounty notice on a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387395/339911)

Т.о. проблема должна решаться на уровне разработчиков сайта, а не переводчиками.

Нашёлся также пункт по пробелу именно для предложенной правки на [enSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423591/3240681).

Comment: По поводу последней правки. Спасибо за ссылку. Это гениально, конечно: "*the fact that there "aren't any answers" on the other Meta question simply indicates that there isn't anything to say about it yet*". Я так понимаю есть множество нерешённых проблем разработчиками, но, ладно, на ruSO не дубликат по крайней мере.