# Нет пробела в настройке отслеживаемых и игнорируемых меток

Tags: дефект, игнорируемые-метки, отслеживаемые-метки

На странице [предпочтений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/) есть возможность редактировать отслеживаемые и игнорируемые метки.

Там нет одного пробела между кнопками "Добавить метку" и "Готово". Был недавно похожий баг с конкурсами и предлагаемыми правками. Но его [исправили](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12999/532877), вот только почему-то с метками проблема:

[image: скрин дефекта]

Comment: Об этом уже [известно](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385385/339911). Там не в пробеле дело, а в том, что должно отображаться что-то одно только. К локализации это не относится.